# Safari issues with javascript + css

Tags: javascript, css, safari, debugging, overlap

I have some strange behavior going on with safari, im using the jQuery.GridLayout plugin and css for styling.

Just for some context, this website layout is a simple header followed by the content which are a collection of blocks (each block is a div) positioned by the javascript and rearranged every time the window is re-sized.

When I direct safari to the website url all the blocks overlap to some degree (like 50%) but as I re-size the window if they have to move, automatically all goes to the correct place and only breaks if I refresh the page.

So it seems that loading the page is messing it up either because something fails to register or because something does not happen until I re-size the window.

As anyone experienced such behavior within safari?

It works perfectly in firefox and opera, its an valid html 4.01 transitional page and the css is also validated (wc3 wise that is).

I know that publishing the code is invaluable to sort this kind of issues but this is a production project and I'm obliged not to it.

Either way I appreciate any advice on were to start looking?

How do one goes about debugging this issues in safari?

Thank you.

Comment: slowly start removing all the elements one-by-one and see if your output gets fixed. the minute it gets fixed you will know what the problem is. start off with removing the inner most div, then its parent etc. and so on.

Comment: A clasic one :) thank you, i've been removing some content to see how it goes I've noticed my margins are off in safari, im inclined to believe my css could be doing something it should not, actually it looks much more like spaghetti than actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Safari fires DomReady before linked resources are loaded. This race condition regarding calculating sizes of elements defined in CSS can usually be avoided by loading your CSS resources before any JavaScript (eg: make sure the  tags appear in the  before ANY  tags (which are blocking, but give a change for CSS to load asynchronously). Worse case scenario, move your  blocks to the last element in , leaving your  tags above.

CSS concatenation of multiple files (if you have them) is also recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't able to post the actual code of the page for us, you might find your solution while trying to reproduce the problem without your specific content.  In the past, I've solved some of my own problems while trying to generate a page that shows the problem to post on IRC / SO.  If you are able to reproduce the problem without your content, post it for the community, and an answer will be much easier to find.

My shot-in-the-dark guesses lead towards:

- You may find that one of your content blocks is causing the issue.
- You may find that a different library you are using is causing the issue.
- Some javascript code for your layout may be running before everything is ready / filled in.  From my memory, Safari is quick to display pages before images are loaded for instance.
- Perhaps you need to specify the an exact width/height of some of your Grid Containers.

Comment: Thank you, Ill make one similar and post as soon as I can, one thing I noticed now is that one of the blocks thats different because it will house the "news", has a similar shape but does not uses images except for the background/top/bottom, its construction its almost similar to the other blocks if I use just that one (repeat) they stop over lapping although the margins are a bit wrong and get fixed if I re-size.

Comment: All content blocks for now are equal except the "news" one, none has heavy images on them nor content, a few 6/7 kines of text, the image is something like 168x168.

Im using just this library jQuery.gridLayout.

Thats very interesting and what I would hope to hear, that safari has some quirks in loading stuff before they are ready, but since im testing it locally its a bit odd, perhaps the java script needs a bit more time to execute.

My blocks do have a specified width but no height, I might try specifying at least the min height.

Comment: If the browser resize event firing is fixing the layout, have you thought about manually refreshing the layout 100ms after document ready?  It doesn't truly solve your problem but may work as a band-aid work around.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, it does work, but if I refresh the page the margins get wrong again, now im fixing my fix :P, more seriously, perhaps safari is indeed loading stuff too fast for the js to execute properly. This thing troubles very much me because originally I wanted to go with pure html/css as my javascript skills are non existent, I can mess with the code but im not really comfortable with it since my understanding is pretty poor. Thanks for your help I will keep this thread updated until I find whats causing it for sure, as soon as I can Ill update with an example page.

Answer (score 0):

Small update:

(new update at bottom)

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/safaribenchmarks.html

And also something that is working is this small script:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
 // CREDITS: 
 // Automatic Page Refresher by  Peter Gehrig and Urs Dudli www.24fun.com 
 // Permission given to use the script provided that this notice remains as is. 
  // Additional scripts can be found at http:
  //www.hypergurl.com 
 // Configure refresh interval (in seconds) 
 var refreshinterval=20 
 // Shall the coundown be displayed inside your status bar? Say "yes" or "no" below:
 var displaycountdown="yes" 
 // Do not edit the code below 
 var starttime 
 var nowtime 
 var reloadseconds=0 
 var secondssinceloaded=0 
 function starttime() { starttime=new Date() starttime=starttime.getTime() countdown() 
 } function countdown() { nowtime= new Date() nowtime=nowtime.getTime()      secondssinceloaded=(nowtime-starttime)/1000 
 reloadseconds=Math.round(refreshinterval-secondssinceloaded) if      (refreshinterval>=secondssinceloaded) 
  { var timer=setTimeout("countdown()",1000) if (displaycountdown=="yes") 
  { window.status="Page refreshing in "+reloadseconds+ " seconds" 
  } } else { clearTimeout(timer) window.location.reload(true) } }            window.onload=starttime 
 </script>
```

I find it odd that a refreshing script solves the issue in safari, but if i manually refresh the page the page havoc ensues...

`########UPDATE`##########

Well I finally got some more time to work on this and after doing some reading a rather obvious thing came to my mind, let the content load and then format it, so for now all of my js sits between `</body>` and `</html>`.

Its not perfect since now you can catch a glimpse of the content without being properly placed when the page first loads.

Maybe ill try calling the js a second time after a few ms have passed of loading.

I know this was proposed a bit upper the thread I just needed time to get my hands dirty thanks all, Ill keep updating till I get it solved in a more proper fashion :)